# Find all complex numbers z such that $\Im(-z+i) = (z+i)^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\Im(-z+i) = (z+i)^2$$

So I tried solving this by replacing $z=a+bi$, thus getting $$\Im(-a+(1-b)i) = (a+(b+1)i)^2$$

From here I split it into the imaginery and real part:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
 -a &= a^2 -(b+1)^2 \\ 
1-b &= 2ab + 2a - 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Now, I can't seem to solve this set without getting a 4th degree $b$. So I'm thinking my logic elsewhere is flawed. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just realised I had entered the wrong information. I'm so sorry! @lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED!

The imaginary part of a complex number is always a real number.
Hence, in order to solve your equation you have to impose that

$\Im\left((z+1)^2\right)=0$

$\Re\left((z+1)^2\right)=\Im(-z+i)$

I.e. solve the following system:

$2ab+2b=2b(a+1)=0$ from which you have $b=0$ or $a=-1$.

$(a+1)^2-b^2=1-b$ that becomes: $\;\;a=0,-2$ if we choose $b=0$ in the previous line... or becomes $b^2-b+1=0$ if you choose $a=-1$ in the previous line which has no solution.

Hence you have two solutions: $z_1=0$, $z_2=-2$.

Comment: I'm trying my best to solve this at the moment. I can't quite see how you got to 2b+2? I think I'm having some difficulties grasping this issue!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake! It was NOT $2b+2$ but $2ab+2b$: it's just the imaginary part of $(z+1)^2$. Sorry!

Comment: I got the same now, but with the values of $a,b$ swapped.

Comment: My girlfriend forced me to abandon this marvelous website. I'm so disperate. This maybe could be my last answer. Bye Erlend, it was a pleasure to answer to your problem, I wish you a bright future in Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real

$$\implies z+1=(a+1)+ib\implies (z+1)^2=(a+1)^2-b^2+2ib(a+1)$$

and $\displaystyle\Im(-a+(1-b)i) =1-b $

Now equate the imaginary part to get $b\cdot(a+1)=0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Honestly, @lab bhattacharjee, I fell off on the first line of this. :-( I realise your $z+1$ logic, but how can it be equal to the inserting method, i.e. $z+1 = a+i(b+1)$? Just got an epiphany as I wrote this. Give me a minute!

Comment: well my epiphany ended in tears. What do you mean by equating the imaginary part to get $b(a+1) = 0$?

Comment: @Erlend, We have $$(a+1)^2-b^2+2ib(a+1)=1-b$$ right? So, equate the imaginary parts

Comment: Id est $2b(a+1) = 0$?

Comment: @Erlend, So, the product of two terms is zero, right? Deal each case separately

Comment: Giving $a=-1$ or $b=0$. So I have two values.

Comment: @Erlend, Now equate the real parts, set the values one by one

Comment: Giving me $\sqrt{2} = a$ and a complex solution for $b$.

Comment: @Erlend, $$b=0\implies(a+1)^2=1\iff a+1=1\implies a=0$$ and $$a+1=0\iff a=-1,-b^2=1-b\iff b^2-b+1=0$$ which is impossible as $b$ is real

Comment: Yeah, I literally have no clue what's going on now. You did it in a way I couldn't grasp from the start with your z+1 logic (albeit a nicer logic), whilst I said $z+1=a+i(b+1)$. I can't follow - I literally can not. Been at this task for so long I'm seeing stars, so I reckon I'll call it a day. Thank you so much for your efforts to help me. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The LHS notation is saying that the **imaginary component** of $-z+i$ equals the RHS.  You are instead solving $-z+i = (z+i)^2$, which is easier to do by solving the corresponding quadratic in $z$.

As you have written the question, the first thing to realize is that $(z+i)^2$ must be real, with no imaginary component.  What restriction does this place on $z$?